# Using PHP's session_start(); more than once? Will it clear the past session's variables?

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently developing in PHP, and I need to know if using

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

More than once in a script, or on a page/site will clear the variables or have any effect? If so how can I use this dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.